# Is there a difference between [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:] and mutableCopy?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Is there a difference between the following ways to create a mutable dictionary?

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict2];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [dict2 mutableCopy]
```

Answer (score 10):

If `dict2` is `nil`, `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict2]` will return an empty dictionary and `[dict2 mutableCopy]` will return `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

A subtle difference is that the `dictionaryWithDictionary:` class method returns an autoreleased object, while the `mutableCopy` method returns a retained object. If you are using automatic reference counting, there is no difference; if you turn ARC off, you need to send a `release` message to the `dict` obtained through the second snippet.

Comment: If `dict2` is nil, `mutableCopy` will return `nil` whereas `dictionaryWithDictionary:nil` will always return an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict2];
```

- Returns an `autoreleased` object.
- If `dict2` is `nil`, still returns a valid, empty `NSMutableDictionary`.

`NSMutableDictionary *dict = [dict2 mutableCopy];`

- Returns a `copied` object that you are responsible for releasing (in non-ARC MRR).
- If `dict2` is `nil`, returns `nil`.